# Null in text when orientation is changed...!

Tags: android

I have a slideshow item. who's image is enlargeable. when i click on image on the slide it gets enlarged and when i tap the screen text related to that image displays on screen. But when i change the orientation of the emulator or phone, the in the text portion "null" is displayed which is not required, and when i move through the slideshow items in the enlarged view, the related text goes fine, when again i change orientation the slideshow item that was opened with text on it, shows null and when i move through text appears fine and so on....!!!

what should i do...??? So that i can get the text related to that slideshow item as well which was opened before the orientation was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

freeze the UI on orientation change.

Add the following to the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

so it looks like

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:name=".your.package">
```